# Do I just need an EC2 instance with more memory or does this error suggest issues in my code?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, amazon-ec2

The short answer is "of course there are problems in my code," but for the time being, I'm wondering if the error messages I'm receiving can help me fix a specific problem.  My app is running on [sails](https://sailsjs.com/), using Node v8.1.2 running on an EC2 instance modified from [this Bitnami image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NNZUAKO).  The instance type is [t2.small](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) (2GB memory), which I should probably upgrade, in any case.

Is this an error message I should review closely and use to find bugs?  Or should I just switch to a larger instance and hope for the best?  Thanks in advance.

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~$ sudo forever stopall
^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
<--- Last few GCs --->

[5547:0x3ec5a50]   111819 ms: Scavenge 6.7 (10.0) -> 6.3 (10.5) MB, 153.7 / 2.2 ms  allocation failure
[5547:0x3ec5a50]   130817 ms: Scavenge 7.3 (10.5) -> 6.8 (11.0) MB, 207.3 / 9.4 ms  allocation failure
[5547:0x3ec5a50]   164550 ms: Scavenge 7.8 (11.0) -> 7.3 (11.5) MB, 155.3 / 8.0 ms  allocation failure
[5547:0x3ec5a50]   203571 ms: Scavenge 8.2 (11.5) -> 7.6 (11.5) MB, 317.2 / 42.5 ms  allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x9d40a2a9891 <JS Object>
    1: patch [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:64] [pc=0x426fa5d7cb1](this=0x38dbb211729 <JS Global Object>,fs=0xfd51435b869 <an Object with deprecated map 0x4376127ec19>)
    2: patch [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:58] [pc=0x426fa5d6791](this=0x38dbb211729 <JS Global Object>,fs=0xfd51435b869...

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 2: 0x13647ec [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewMap(v8::internal::InstanceType, int, v8::internal::ElementsKind) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 8: v8::internal::Map::RawCopy(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 9: v8::internal::Map::CopyDropDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
10: v8::internal::Map::AddMissingTransitions(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::DescriptorArray>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::LayoutDescriptor>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
11: v8::internal::MapUpdater::ConstructNewMap() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
12: v8::internal::MapUpdater::ReconfigureToDataField(int, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::PropertyConstness, v8::internal::Representation, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FieldType>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
13: 0xffc3a0 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
14: v8::internal::Map::PrepareForDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::PropertyConstness, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
15: v8::internal::LookupIterator::PrepareForDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
16: v8::internal::Object::SetDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
17: v8::internal::Object::SetPropertyInternal(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed, bool*) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
18: v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
19: v8::internal::StoreIC::Store(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
20: v8::internal::Runtime_StoreIC_Miss(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
21: 0x426fa38437d
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~$ <--- JS stacktrace --->^C
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~$ cd my-sails-api/
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~/my-sails-api$ sudo sails lift


<--- Last few GCs --->

[5562:0x2739a40]    79195 ms: Scavenge 5.7 (10.1) -> 5.6 (9.6) MB, 304.7 / 8.1 ms  allocation failure
[5562:0x2739a40]    98188 ms: Scavenge 6.6 (9.6) -> 5.9 (10.1) MB, 252.5 / 24.5 ms  allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x25f39c629891 <JS Object>
    2: constructor(aka Duplex) [_stream_duplex.js:48] [pc=0x178f7677eb54](this=0x20617eab9791 <a WriteStream with map 0x1d0c9952641>,options=0x20617eab98e9 <an Object with map 0x1d0c9952329>)
    3: constructor(aka Socket) [net.js:197] [pc=0x178f7677de42](this=0x20617eab9791 <a WriteStream with map 0x1d0c9952641>,options=0x20617eab98e9 <an Object with map 0x1d0c9952329>)
    4: new constructor(...

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 2: 0x13647ec [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 7: v8::internal::Factory::NewCode(v8::internal::CodeDesc const&, unsigned int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, bool, int, bool) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 8: v8::internal::CodeGenerator::MakeCodeEpilogue(v8::internal::MacroAssembler*, v8::internal::EhFrameWriter*, v8::internal::CompilationInfo*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
 9: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::MakeCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*, unsigned long) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
10: v8::internal::FullCodegenCompilationJob::ExecuteJobImpl() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
11: v8::internal::CompilationJob::ExecuteJob() [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
12: 0xd97d90 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
13: 0xd98b28 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
14: 0xd98d8f [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
15: 0xd9ce59 [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
16: v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
17: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileLazy(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin]
18: 0x178f7658437d
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~/my-sails-api$
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~/my-sails-api$ sudo sails lift
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
bitnami@ip-172-31-17-108:~/my-sails-api$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default node.js will not allow you to allocate more than 1.7GB in one process so no - there's no point in upgrading unless you're sure you can't do anything in your code to consume less memory (for example use streams).

If you have no other choice you can try to increase the size of allowed memory - but keep in mind that it will probably impact the speed of your program - by setting the following option:

```
--max_old_space_size <size in mb>
```

Run `node --v8-options` for more information.